# WordPress do_action hooks seems to ignore unsaved customizer changes?

Tags: wordpress

In my WordPress theme, I have a drag and drop sort-able field, with the goal to arrange the order of the header and the navigation menus, so that I can choose if I want to display the menus above or below the header.

[image]

In my header.php file, I am using: `do_action( 'mytheme_header' );`

In my function.php file, I am adding the actions:

```
add_action( 'mytheme_header', 'mytheme_do_header', get_theme_mod( 'mytheme_header_position', '1' ) );
add_action( 'mytheme_header', 'mytheme_do_nav_primary', get_theme_mod( 'mytheme_nav_primary_position', '2' ) );
add_action( 'mytheme_header', 'mytheme_do_nav_secondary', get_theme_mod( 'mytheme_nav_secondary_position', '3' ) );
```

The `mytheme_do_$` are functions which output the html part of the header/menus.

So far so good. On the live website, it works as intended.
However inside of the customizer, when I drag and drop the items around, to create a new order, the customizer refreshes, but it always uses the old arrangement, from when I last saved the theme settings.
I noticed only after I hit "Save & Publish", and then refresh the page by making another change, it shows the new arrangement.

It seems that `do_action` or `add_action` is not using the unsaved values of `get_theme_mod` created by the customizer.
When I echo the values of `get_theme_mod( 'mytheme_header_position', '1' )`, they show the correct updated value on each customizer refresh.

I assume that `do_action` or `add_action` are executed before the unsaved `get_theme_mod` is executed?

If so, how can I get the temporary unsaved customizer `get_theme_mod` values inside the actions hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the `add_action` hooks that use `get_theme_mod` inside of `wp_loaded`, solves the issue. This way the hooks are not executed until wordpress is fully loaded and the customizer has time to get the unsaved values.

```
function do_header_wp_loaded() {
    add_action( 'mytheme_header', 'mytheme_do_header', get_theme_mod( 'mytheme_header_position', '1' ) );
    add_action( 'mytheme_header', 'mytheme_do_nav_primary', get_theme_mod( 'mytheme_nav_primary_position', '2' ) );
    add_action( 'mytheme_header', 'mytheme_do_nav_secondary', get_theme_mod( 'mytheme_nav_secondary_position', '3' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'do_header_wp_loaded' );
```